# Counts of rows grouped by time frames

Tags: sql, postgresql

What do I have:

```
| id | timestamp  |
| ---| -----------|
| 1  | 1453212172 |
| 2  | 1453512172 |
| 3  | 1453712172 |
...
```

I want to get the count of entries grouped by time frames. Starting with 2015-11-01 20:00 I need the count for a group lasting 3 days:

```
| count | from       | to
| ------| -----------|-----------
| 34    | day 0, 8am | day 3, 8am
| 10    | day 3, 8am | day 6, 8am
| 56    | day 6, 8am | day 9, 8am
...
```

What I found were only for whole days. Is there a nice way to do that on the database layer? The only way I get it running were with multiple queries and calculate it on the application layer, but it's too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're storing the data as timestamps, surely you can do this with a simple calculation, as 3 days is:

```
24 x 60 * 60 = 86400
```

In conjunction with a stored procedure which gets the minimum and maximum timestamps for the dataset, converts them to integers and then uses a `WHILE` loop to iterate through the data until it reaches the end, returning a summary row as you need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_counts() RETURNS TABLE(row_count integer, from_time integer, to_time integer)
AS $BODY$
  DECLARE 
    current_timestamp INTEGER;
    maximum_timestamp INTEGER;
    next_timestamp INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    current_timestamp := (SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(epoch FROM MIN(timestamp)) AS integer) FROM test);
    maximum_timestamp := (SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(epoch FROM MAX(timestamp)) AS integer) FROM test);

    WHILE current_timestamp < maximum_timestamp LOOP
      next_timestamp := current_timestamp + 86400;
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (SELECT COUNT(*) AS row_count, current_timestamp AS from_time, next_timestamp AS to_time FROM test WHERE CAST(EXTRACT(epoch FROM(timestamp)) AS integer) >= current_timestamp AND CAST(EXTRACT(epoch FROM(timestamp)) AS integer) < next_timestamp);
      current_timestamp := next_timestamp;
    END LOOP;
  END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

That procedure is untested and will probably not work out of the box, but gives you an idea of what you can do. You can then convert back from the integer timestamp to a true timestamp on your app side.

Comment: I dont' have any working query yet. But what you suggest is just a select for rows in a time frame. I want to have them grouped by time frame.

Comment: Your question has changed since I answered, I'll update my answer

Comment: I didn't change the meaning of my question but it made more clear. Thanks for you answer, but a function is not what I wanted to have. I would do it on the application layer than. I hoped for a solution with 'normal' query logic. I appreciate your effort. Have not tested your solution yet.

Comment: _"surely you can do this with a simple calculation, as 3 days is: 24 x 60 * 60 = 86400"_ Not if you are working with calendar days and DST.